# How do I send push notifications with expo and react native?

Tags: push-notification, notifications, expo-notifications

I am writing a simple app, where I need to send push notifications. For instance, a user liked a post -> send a push notification; or a user commented under a post -> send a push notification; or a user sent you a message -> send a push notification.

I am using `Notifications` from `expo-notifications`. I have set up my `Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener` and `Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener`. I tested them using [Expo's push notification tool](https://expo.dev/notifications) and it all works fine.

However, I am struggling to send notifications. As suggested per [expo's docs](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications/) they have a library for `Node.js` called [expo-server-sdk-node](https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node) which takes care of sending notifications. As per their doc:

> The Expo push notification service accepts batches of notifications
> so that you don't need to send 1000 requests to send 1000
> notifications. We recommend you batch your notifications to reduce
> the number of requests  and to compress them (notifications with
> similar content will get compressed).

And I agree with the above statement. Sending notifications on batch makes sense, however, I have a question regarding this:

1. How do I implement it? Do I keep counter on the user's notification, and lets say, the user has liked 10 posts -> then I send 10 notifications as a batch request? What if they liked 8 posts and then closed the app? Do I send the notifications on closing the app? It doesn't seem right to me. Also, if the user has sent a message, I believe I should straight away send the notification, rather than waiting for a batch request for the user to send 10 messages.

The implementation they offer on their docs is the following:

```
// Create the messages that you want to send to clients
let messages = [];
for (let pushToken of somePushTokens) {
  // Each push token looks like ExponentPushToken[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]

  // Check that all your push tokens appear to be valid Expo push tokens
  if (!Expo.isExpoPushToken(pushToken)) {
    console.error(`Push token ${pushToken} is not a valid Expo push token`);
    continue;
  }

  // Construct a message (see https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/sending-notifications/)
  messages.push({
    to: pushToken,
    sound: 'default',
    body: 'This is a test notification',
    data: { withSome: 'data' },
  })
}
```

Which is OK and understandable. But then I struggle with the next step:

```
let chunks = expo.chunkPushNotifications(messages);
let tickets = [];
(async () => {
  
  for (let chunk of chunks) {
    try {
      let ticketChunk = await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk);
      console.log(ticketChunk);
      tickets.push(...ticketChunk);
     
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
})();
```

That is, at which point do I call `expo.chunkPushNotifications(messages)` and then `await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk)`. Do I wait 10 similar notifications to be collected, do I wait some time, do I do it when the user closes the app, or something else?

Comment: Please see this expo document and sample code: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/overview/